# How to create a smooth 3D effect on text?

Tags: fonts, inkscape, 3d, effects, filter

In Inkscape, I used to be able to apply the combined lighting filter over text for a great smooth, 3d lighting effect on text but am not able to with updated version. How do I create this effect on text?? Please refer to attached image.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look at this, and it looks like it might be a bug. Comparing the *Bevels > Combined Lighting* filter in Inkscape 0.48 and 0.92, there is some difference in how the filter is working, even though the settings seem to be the same. Funny thing is, if I copy and paste something from 0.48 into 0.92, it works. So there must be something different in the way 0.92 is applying the same filter. It doesn't seem to be a rendering problem, because 0.92 can display the filter from 0.48 just fine.

I've shared [the SVG here](https://svgshare.com/i/5rX.svg) if anyone more knowledgeable wants to investigate further.

This is a screenshot of the two effects side by side, shown in Inkscape 0.92

[image]

Update:

On further investigation of the XML, I noticed that there are some differences in the SVG for the text. In 0.48 there seems to be a transform matrix being added, so alerting me to the fact that the effect is somehow being scaled differently with the text in 0.92. So I experimented in 0.92, and applied the combined lighting filter to a larger piece of text, then simply scaled it down afterwards. And voila, it seems to work! Not exactly a fix, but at least a workaround with only a little more faffing.

[image]

Comment: Something useful - again! Hopefully we will see many more!

Comment: @user287001 what's annoying about stuff like this is that there shouldn't really be such glaring differences like this between versions. Some changes made in the most recent version of Inkscape can make it look like it's broken, whereas the truth is it just does things differently.

Comment: This suggested workaround works in Inkscape 1.1.1 as well, i.e. apply filter on a very large size, then reduce the size as required, and filter works well.